# Start service when user is driving

Tags: android

I am trying to disable all sounds and vibration of phone when user is detected to be driving. Now is there any way i can register a broadcast receiver using this [api](http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html) so that I can get a broadcast when user is detected to be driving and I can disable all sounds?

I am successfully detect that the user is driving via activity recognition with above given API, only when my app is running. I am just trying to figure out a way to get a broadcast when the app is not running.

Comment: Moreover, what is your definition of "driving" that can be determined objectively? Clearly, it cannot be movement, because there is plenty of movement that would not be considered "driving", including being a passenger.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think the user would rely on this property http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity.html - A new one for me I must admit

Comment: Which will be of great annoyance to bus passengers...

Comment: I updated my question. @CommonsWare I get IN_VEHICLE flag with an associated confidence. Android itself handles how it thinks the user is driving. I will be handling passengers mode later on so thats not an issue for now.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on some car software right now and the way that I am detecting "driving" context of the phone is that it is paired with a specific hands free device via bluetooth. I let the user choose what Bluetooth pairing to use as a trigger for "in car as driver" context. Works like a charm.

Comment: Or it could be NFC tag in car as well - in this case you just need to touch phone to tag (of course, NFC should be enabled and screen unlocked)

Comment: Yes. I've done some projects with NFC. The problem there is when you leave the car. You have to touch the tag again. Then you have to track in/out, and if you miss once, you get out of state. With the Bluetooth, you know that you are in the car if the device is paired. I am using an ODB2 dongle that is always in my car, but a handsfree kit works good too.